# Modifying NSFetchRequest generating NSRangeException index 0 beyond bounds for empty array

Tags: ios, core-data, nsfetchrequest, nsrangeexception

In my latest iOS App Update, I'm seeing a significant increase in DB related crashes.  I'm seeing crashes from almost every line of code that runs a fetch on the DB.

Exception:

`NSRangeException

* -[__NSArrayM objectAtIndex:]: index 0 beyond bounds for empty array`

Stack Trace:

CoreFoundation 0x32c982a3 __exceptionPreprocess + 163
1
libobjc.A.dylib 0x3a93d97f objc_exception_throw + 31
2
CoreFoundation 0x32be3b75 -[__NSArrayM objectAtIndex:] + 165
3
CoreData 0x32a4227f -[NSSQLCore _newRowsForFetchPlan:selectedBy:withArgument:] + 2007
4
CoreData 0x32a3b089 -[NSSQLCore newRowsForFetchPlan:] + 313
5
CoreData 0x32a3a73f -[NSSQLCore objectsForFetchRequest:inContext:] + 683
6
CoreData 0x32a3a205 -[NSSQLCore executeRequest:withContext:error:] + 469
7
CoreData 0x32a3961d -[NSPersistentStoreCoordinator executeRequest:withContext:error:] + 1645
8
CoreData 0x32a37f17 -[NSManagedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:error:] + 647
9
MyApp 0x000516b7 +[DBQuery searchObjectsWithEntityName:::::] + 211
10
MyApp 0x000515a1 +[DBQuery syncData] + 113
11
MyApp 0x0006a7f7 __14+[MyAppSync sync]_block_invoke + 39
12
libdispatch.dylib 0x3ad5511f _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 11
13
libdispatch.dylib 0x3ad63259 _dispatch_root_queue_drain + 261
14
libdispatch.dylib 0x3ad633b9 _dispatch_worker_thread2 + 85
15
libsystem_c.dylib 0x3ad89a11 _pthread_wqthread + 361
16
libsystem_c.dylib 0x3ad898a4 start_wqthread + 8

It looks like the culprit lines of code might be related to adding two lines of modification of my NSFetchRequest:

`+ (NSFetchRequest*) getFetchRequestForEntityName:(NSString*)entityName :(NSPredicate*)predicate :(NSString*)sortKey :(BOOL)sortAscending :(int)limit :(NSManagedObjectContext*)managedObjectContext
{
    NSFetchRequest *request = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
    NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:entityName inManagedObjectContext:managedObjectContext];
    [request setEntity:entity];`

```
[request setFetchLimit:limit];
```

//*** NEW IN LATEST RELEASE  **//

```
[request setIncludesPropertyValues:NO];
[request setReturnsObjectsAsFaults:NO];
```

//****************************//

```
if(predicate != nil)
{
    [request setPredicate:predicate];
}

// If a sort key was passed, use it for sorting.
if(sortKey != nil)
{
    NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:sortKey ascending:sortAscending];
    NSArray *sortDescriptors = @[sortDescriptor];
    [request setSortDescriptors:sortDescriptors];
}

return request;
```

}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Removing the two added lines fixed the problem.

`[request setIncludesPropertyValues:NO]; 

[request setReturnsObjectsAsFaults:NO];`

Comment: With iOS10 this error occured for me, while on iOS9 it was working fine. Removing ANY of those two lines fixes it...